# STM32 Cube IDE - after initial successfull launch and use now remains idle during splash screen launch stage (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with the official Debian installer of STM32 Cube IDE (latest version), downloaded directly from STM's website.

After installing everything (default installation, which is in `/opt/st/`) I launched the IDE and started playing with it. I managed to quickly find my way (even with my poor skills both with my board and ARM in general) to creating, building and launching a simply blinky test program (blinking the two LEDs) for my STM32L-Discovery board.

The issue now is that on the next day I could no longer launch the IDE. And it has been like that ever since. Once started (both from the launcher created by the installation in the menu (I have XFCE) and via terminal) the IDE remains idle after the progress bar in the splash screen fills up:

[image: STM32 Cube IDE - freeze on splash screen]

The weird thing is that in `htop` I see no activity whatsoever:

[[image: htop - no activity from STM32 Cube IDE]

It remains like this forever. Well, forever here means 20-30 minutes until my patience runs out. :D

I see that the launcher starts the **Wayland** version. I tried the other one just in case although that should not be an issue (even with my old laptop) since the first time after the installation it started.

Anyone know a solution? I can try reinstalling and also removing my workspace, although the latter is something the IDE doesn't seem to even go for at this point.

Comment: If your issue is solved, please close this question by clicking the "Accept answer" tick. This will help other members of the community find this response more quickly :)

Comment: @Wonky The problem is only partially solved. It is still unclear why the workspace get corrupted. I experienced this several times. The solution would be to not only say "Delete this and that" but hopefully point to an actual bug report regarding this problem, so that people can track the progress in the actual solution.

Comment: STM32CubeIDE is not open source, so nothing like Issues in GitHub where you can see bug reports. You can file in your own bug here https://community.st.com/s/onlinesupport

I think as of 1.11.x version is fixed, you can also check the wiki errata to see known issues and fixes. But I don't think this is the point, for a propietary software knowing what caused this corruption is out of the scope. If you want to give it a go, feel free. Edited my answer to add the errata pages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Workaround**

To fix this, just remove this file inside your workspace:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

Hope this solves the issue.

(this file is the responsible of saving your workbench layout)

**Where to look for fixes and issues**

[STM32CubeIDE 1.11.x](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/STM32CubeIDE:STM32CubeIDE_errata_1.11.x#Fixed_issues)

[STM32CubeIDE 1.10.x](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/STM32CubeIDE:STM32CubeIDE_errata_1.10.x)

**Updates**

As of 1.11.x I believe its fixed, not encountered this issue again. For me it happened when I forgot to charge my laptop and it shutdown while having STM32cubeIDE open.

Good luck.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04, thanks!

Comment: This happened to me on ubuntu 22.04 and 1.12. 


`rm -rf ./STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.12.0/.metadata`

fixed it, ta